# How to start a django app

Tags: python, django, apple-push-notifications

I'm trying to use django-ios-notifications to server PUSH notifications via APNS (https://github.com/stephenmuss/django-ios-notifications).  I've never used Django before. I've followed the instructions on the modules github page, but have'nt been able to get it working. I've done the following;

*installed required package and django
*added  'ios_notifications', to my INSTALLED_APPS settings file
*synced my local MySQL server with django (a load of new tables were created, for both django and django-ios-notifications, so it appears to be installed correctly, which I was thrilled about)
*start django server

However when I go to the modules config page (URL below) I just see the default 'It worked!
Congratulations on your first Django-powered page.' holding page, not the admin page I expected. (the tutorial on the github page descried a form)

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/ios_notifications/apnservice/add/
```

I guess I need to configure something in djange, I read over the first few pages on the django tutorial but I couldn't see any mention of using installed modules. I'm sure this is a very simple problem to solve, so if anyone could point me in the right direction that would be fantastic.

https://github.com/stephenmuss/django-ios-notifications

Answer (score 1):

You don't seem to have activated Django's admin interface, which you need to access the admin forms. There are [concise instructions in the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/contrib/admin/). You can switch to a different version of Django in the lower right corner, if you aren't using 1.5.